# How to load php code dynamically and check if classes implement interface

Tags: php, class, interface

I'm loading a class dynamically in PHP. This file and class name are gotten out of the database. This file must contain a class and a method. I tried to solve it with an interface, but I don't really get it how I could do it the most beautiful way.

What would be your suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`class_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) to determine if a class has been defined, [`method_exists()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to determine if a class has a method and [`instanceof`](http://us.php.net/instanceof) to determine if a class implements an interface.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a class has been defined, use:

```
   if (class_exists('ClassName')) {
      // Do something
   }
```

To check whether a method/function exists, use:

```
   if (method_exists('methodName')) {
      // Do something
   }
```

Comment: You mean if a class has been **defined**, not instantiated. An instantiated class yields an object.