# php - check if class name stored in a string is implementing an interface

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I understand that my question is somehow wrong, but I'm still trying to solve this problem.

I have an interface `Programmer`:

```
interface Programmer {
    public function writeCode();
}
```

and a couple of **namespaced** classes:

- `Students\BjarneProgrammer` (implements `Programmer`)
- `Students\CharlieActor` (implements `Actor`)

I have this class names stored in array `$students = array("BjarneProgrammer", "CharlieActor");`

I want to write a function, that will return an instance of class if it's implementing `Programmer` interface.

**Examples:**

`getStudentObject($students[0]);` - It should return an instance of `BjarneProgrammer` because it's implementing Programmer.

`getStudentObject($students[1]);` - It should return `false` because Charlie is not a Programmer.

I tried it using `instanceof` operator, but the main problem is that I **do not** want to instantiate an object if it's not implementing Programmer.

I checked [How to load php code dynamically and check if classes implement interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604090/how-to-load-php-code-dynamically-and-check-if-classes-implement-interface), but there is no appropriate answer as I don't want to create object unless it's returned by function.

Comment: @how: The OP says they don't want to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [class_implements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) (requires `PHP 5.1.0`)

```
interface MyInterface { }
class MyClass implements MyInterface { }

$interfaces = class_implements('MyClass');
if($interfaces && in_array('MyInterface', $interfaces)) {
    // Class MyClass implements interface MyInterface
}
```

You can pass the `class name` as a string as function's argument. Also, you may use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
if ( $class->implementsInterface('MyInterface') ) {
    // Class MyClass implements interface MyInterface
}
```

**Update :** (You may try something like this)

```
interface Programmer {
    public function writeCode();
}

interface Actor {
    // ...
}

class BjarneProgrammer implements Programmer {
    public function writeCode()
    {
        echo 'Implemented writeCode method from Programmer Interface!';
    }
}
```

Function that checks and returns `instanse/false`

```
function getStudentObject($cls)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($cls);
    if ( $class->implementsInterface('Programmer') ) {
        return new $cls;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Get an instance or false

```
$students = array("BjarneProgrammer", "CharlieActor");
$c = getStudentObject($students[0]);
if($c) {
    $c->writeCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me. I used just ReflectionClass - http://codepad.org/EvZRbaWZ

Comment: I'm using method from ReflectionClass `return $class->newInstance();` instead of `return new $cls;`. Thanks again :>

Comment: That's fine I think :-)

Answer (score 26):

If you're using a modern version of PHP (5.3.9+), then the easiest (and best) way would be to use [`is_a()`](http://php.net/is_a) with the third parameter `true`:

```
$a = "Stdclass";

var_dump(is_a($a, "stdclass", true));
var_dump(is_a($a, $a, true));
```

Both of those will return true.

Comment: PHP documentation is kind of misleading (if you don't care to read every sentence :) ) - it says first parameter of is_a is an object. But if you read on - you find out it can actually be a string...

Comment: For me, this was the more elegant solution

Answer (score 8):

Use PHP's function [is_subclass_of()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php):

```php
use App\MyClass;
use App\MyInterface;

if (is_subclass_of(MyClass::class, MyInterface::class)) {
    // ...
}
```